# Plans or Blueprints for a game table

Tags: tools, dice

I have been gaming for many years, and now that I have a dedicated room to keep all my gaming stuff, I would like to build a table. So far we have been using a plain dining room table.

Has anyone built one that they could share the plans to? What kinds of things should there be (cup holders, dice trays, etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have a cool idea, but unfortunately these kind of questions aren't a good fit for this site as the answers will be primarily opinion based. Idea generation and discussion topics are better suited to an RPG forum, like the ones on this [curated list](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/41726). For more information on how to ask a good question here, visit our [Help Center](http://www.rpg.stackexchange.com/help). Hope to see you around!

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks David. Should I delete the question?

Comment: You are fine to leave it up. This way if anyone else is wondering they can find this question and understand why it's better to ask elsewhere. :)